Flutter Easyloading: how to apply loading to a specific widget
I am using flutter_easyloading library for my project but I am having a requirement to not showing loading for the whole screen.
I have a screen with two widgets, loading data from two different API calls. I would like to show two loading for these two widgets independently but simultaneously. When the API call is finished, the loading overlay will be removed for the specific widget.
Is there any I can use flutter_easyloading to implement this? Thank you

I think It may not possible because we need to initialize the EasyLoading.init() inside the MaterialApp(). You can check other available packages like: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit
